# Sympy: Conjugates of real-valued functions

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

Why does this not work?

```
In: from sympy import *

    x = symbols('x', real=True)
    f = symbols('f', cls=Function, real=True)
    simplify(f(x)*conjugate(f(x)))

Out: f(x)*conjugate(f(x))
```

I expected `f(x)**2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, functions created with `Function` ignore assumptions. You'll need to create a function by subclassing `Function`, like

```
In [12]: class f(Function):
   ....:     is_real=True
   ....:

In [13]: f(x)
Out[13]: f(x)

In [14]: f(x).conjugate()
Out[14]: f(x)
```